# Deserialization string json from asp to java class

Tags: android, asp.net, json

When I developed my project, I had an error in android activity

json string that return from asp web method is return correctly but when convert json to class the class is equal null (i convert it by google json jar 2.1)

```
   android code:


        //to call my service and get data

        ServiceCall call = new ServiceCall();

    String jsonuserdata = call.getUserData("abced@myservice.com")
            .toString();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonuserdata,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //this Toast message is print data correctly 

         Gson gson = new Gson();

    Type userType = new TypeToken<UserData>(){}.getType();

    UserData user = gson.fromJson(jsonuserdata,userType);


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + user.userid.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

the problem is when I convert json string to class

asp.net web method return a valid json string to android method

```
 [WebMethod]
        public string getUserData(string email)
        {
            UserData user = new UserData();

            user = DataBase.getUserData(email);

            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            string strJSON = js.Serialize(user);

            return strJSON;
        }
```

this is my class in java

```
public class UserData {

    public static Class<UserData> USERDATA_CLASS = UserData.class;



    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }



    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }



    String username;

    String email;

    String password;

    String userid;





    public UserData() {


    }

    public UserData(String id, String name, String age, String weight,
            String height, String calorie, String status, String gender,
            String idealweight, String minidealweight, String maxidealweight,
            String email, String password, String country, String report,String accountstatus) {

        this.userid = id;
        this.username = name;

        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;

    }

    public UserData(UserData user) {


        this.userid = user.userid;
        this.username = user.username;

        this.email = user.email;
        this.password = user.password;

    }

}
```

Comment: {"username":"user","email":"abced@myservice.com","password":"123","userid":"100"} this is the json string

Answer (score 0):

You can parse an instance of the class simply by:

```
Type userType = new TypeToken<UserData>(){}.getType();
UserData user = gson.fromJson(jsonuserdata,userType);
```

->

```
UserData user = gson.fromJson(jsonuserdata, UserData.class);
```

**EDIT** Adding explanation:

Taken from [here](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.reflect.Type%29):

> This method is useful if the specified object is a generic type. For
>   non-generic objects, use fromJson(String, Class) instead.

So you should not use the type parameter, but the class.

Comment: json string that return from asp web method is return correctly (Toast msg print correctly data) but when convert json to class in android the class is equal null (i convert it by google json jar 2.1)

Comment: @Developer what you mean the class is equal to null? Which class?

Comment: UserData user = gson.fromJson(jsonuserdata, UserData.class);  when i print user instance. the result is equal null

Comment: Taken from here: http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson(java.lang.String, java.lang.reflect.Type) `This method is useful if the specified object is a generic type. For non-generic objects, use fromJson(String, Class) instead.` just as I wrote, however I can not justify why if you use the call I suggested it will deserialize into null. Can you check once more, please?

Comment: thank you my friend the solution of my problem is


import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

 @SerializedName("Userid")
 private String userid;
 
 @SerializedName("Username")
 private String username;

and do this for all private members

Comment: Yes I see the json attribute names do not match the names of the class properties. However, nobody could have helped you as long as you put incorrect json in the question. Take care when you post further details on the question, they should not be misleading. Also I assume I am the one that helped you with this question. You really should accept some of the answers you got. Mine is a good candidate.